# substituir hífen por underline htaccess

Tags: php, htaccess

Como substituir o hífen próximo ao número por underline nessa URL(htaccess).

```
www.site.com.br/post/77-eu_tu_eles
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url = "www.site.com.br/post/77-eu_tu_eles";

$urlExplode = explode("-",$url);
$urlImplode = implode("_",$urlExplode);
```

Com a função `explode( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ])`, te retornará um `array`, o `$delimiter` passado, no nosso caso é o "-". O `$delimiter` é utilizado como parâmetro para a separação da `string`.

E logo depois utilizamos o `implode ( string $glue , array $pieces )`, onde pegamos o `array` retornado da função `explode`, que está armazenado na variável `$urlExplode`, e passamos um `$glue` para fazer a junção dos valores do `array`, que no caso é "_".

Comment: Obrigado Jonathan.